# Blender twisting parts of mesh when rigging

Tags: transforms, rigging, rigify, weight-painting

I have a problem when I rig a mesh and that is when I put the arms of my mesh up in the air for example some parts of it get twisted.

I've tried looking at the XYZ orientation and the weight painting with no succes.

Here are pictures illustrating the problem. **(possibly NSFW, hover to view)**

> [image: arms down with no twist]
>
>  [image: twist]

here is the .blend file

[female base rigged](http://pasteall.org/blend/26742)

Comment: You can upload the file to a service such as [pasteall](http://pasteall.org/blend) and then share the link here.

Comment: ok, thanks I just uploaded the file and edited the post.

Comment: This happens only with IK controls on this rigify rig, if you imported this from makehuman you could switch to the mhx rigs where everything works as expected.

Comment: I rigged it the normal  way by applying an armature modifier and then making the automatic weights(ctrl + p) i didnt doa  anything in makehuman,  how can i fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your scene is caused by the bone structure. Take the L side for example:

Since you are using two bones for each upperarm for some reason (which is unlike normal human), the constrained bone `DEF-upper_arm.01.L` doesn't follow the rotation of its control bone or even `DEF-upper_arm.02.L`, which would lead to the problem. As shown below:

[image]

There would be a few ways to fix this, but I'm really not sure why you structed and set the control bone for upper arm like this (I assume you are trying to simulate the natural-looking muscle stretch). However, I think at least an additional **Copy Rotation** constraint on`DEF-upper_arm.01.L` is needed here.

Here is my try, FYI:

[image]

Comment: oh ok, no I'm starting to get it. I'm just learning 3D graphics as I'm mainly a programmer, so, this is kind of hard for me sometimes.

the way i did it was to add an armature and setting the weights to automatic but as those bones appeared as they are i tought that was the normal setup for the armature. the solution is to make the upperarm just one bone? how can i do it? should i re-rig it?

Comment: This is a very complicated rigging. If you are the man who created it, then you may exactly know what you are doing. Yep, you can make it one bone, as well as the lower arm, thighs and shins, since that's how human armature looks like. Or, as I said, you may also add **Copy Rotation** constraint to the `DEF-upper_arm.01.L`, to let it follow the rotation of control bone. If it has to.